# Selecting rows based on condition while using UNION in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, union

I am using UNION to join the two datasets, however I would like to add a filter that if the first three column values are identical in the two sets then take the rows from the first set (tbl).

```
tb1:
col1                col2        col3        col4    col5 col6   col7           col8  
0.004% travoprost   travoprost  travoprost  091340  001  ANDA   Prescription    AT1 

tb2:
0.004% travoprost   travoprost  travoprost  091341  001  ANDA   None (Tentative Approval)   (null)
```

I would like take union of above 2 rows but if the first 3 columns have identical value, then consider tb1 row.

Comment: You mean like `(SELECT * FROM tb1) UNION ALL (SELECT * FROM tb2 WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM tb1 WHERE (tb1.col1, tb1.col2, tb1.col3) = (tb2.col1, tb2.col2, tb2.col3))`?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT col1,col2,col3,coalesce(t1.col4,t2.col4),coalesce(t1.col5,t2.col5),coalesce(t1.col6,t2.col6),coalesce(t1.col7,t2.col7),coalesce(t1.col8,t2.col8)  
  FROM tbl t1 FULL OUTER JOIN tbl2 t2 USING (col1,col2,col3);
```

or

@Bergi solution in comment

depending on your structure, mainly indexes, first one should be quicker.